# How to relax Jenkins security rules for Allure?

Tags: jenkins, allure

I tried to add [this](http://wiki.qatools.ru/display/AL/Allure+Jenkins+Plugin) in Jenkins Script Console, but it didn't help:

`"-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"`

How to do this? Or [what is wrong](http://screencast.com/t/r9vxouhR)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You posted the start parameter for java. If you would like to test it inside the console try this:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';")
```

If you want to change the property for every start, you can add:

```
-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
```

to your start parameter, so that it might look like:

```
java -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" -jar jenkins.war
```

If you need further informations, you can take a look at [JENKINS Configuring Content Security Policy](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy)

Comment: Thank you, [script-result](http://screencast.com/t/Dji5bOxcJBI). But allure report not opened again - [chrome](http://screencast.com/t/lrwW6epC74j) and [safari](http://screencast.com/t/r9vxouhR)

Comment: I removed a parameter, can you try again?

Comment: Hello S.Spieker Do you know how can I make the change permanently?

Comment: @NelsonRaulCaberoMendoza I added the start paramter for enabling this permanently

Comment: Thanks I am using jenkins running on tomcat and I am not sure in wich file I have to add that configuration

Comment: Run the tomcatXw.exe (where X is the major version number of Tomcat you are running) program in Tomcat's bin directory to configure the parameters used for your Tomcat Windows Service. There are lots of things you can do in there including configure any -D-style system properties you want.

Answer (score 0):

The following lines worked for me:

```
System.clearProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP")
System.clearProperty("jenkins.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP")
System.setProperty("jenkins.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:")
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:")
```